# JavaScript modifying an object inside the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am having a problem trying to modify the name of a nested object using map function and to return the modified object.

I was trying the approach with double forEach loop but I am also failing with that.

```js
const myObject = [{
    id: 1,
    childrenList: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'foo',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'foo',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    childrenList: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'foo',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'foo',
      },
    ],
  },
];

const alteredObject = myObject.map((thisChild) => {
  if (thisChild.id === 1) {
    thisChild.childrenList.map((item) => {
      if (item.id === 1) {
        return {
          ...item,
          name: 'bar',
        };
      }
      return item;
    });
  }
  return thisChild;
});

console.log(alteredObject);
```

```
//trying to get:
alteredObject = [
    {
      id: 1,
      childrenList: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'bar',
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'foo',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      childrenList: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'foo',
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'foo',
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
```

This is the first time I am trying to modify a nested object. Normally with an array of objects, I am not having any issue so I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

You only need to update the children with your map and it will work. Like this:

```js
  const myObject = [
    {
      id: 1,
      childrenList: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "foo"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "foo"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      childrenList: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "foo"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "foo"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  const alteredObject = myObject.map((thisChild) => {
    if (thisChild.id === 1) {
      thisChild.childrenList = thisChild.childrenList.map((item) => {
        if (item.id === 1) {
          return {
            ...item,
            name: "bar"
          };
        }
        return item;
      });
    }
    return thisChild;
  });
  console.log(alteredObject);
```

And if you want to do it with forEach:

```js
  const myObject = [
    {
      id: 1,
      childrenList: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "foo"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "foo"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      childrenList: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "foo"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "foo"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  const alteredObject = myObject.map((thisChild) => {
    if (thisChild.id === 1) {
      thisChild.childrenList.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.id === 1) {
          item.name = 'bar';
        }
        return item;
      });
    }
    return thisChild;
  });
  console.log(alteredObject);
```

If you can modify your object then you can do it with two forEach:

```js
  const myObject = [
    {
      id: 1,
      childrenList: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "foo"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "foo"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      childrenList: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "foo"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "foo"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

 myObject.forEach((thisChild) => {
    if (thisChild.id === 1) {
      thisChild.childrenList.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.id === 1) {
          item.name = 'bar';
        }
        return item;
      });
    }
  });
  console.log(myObject);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks.
Just a question - isn't 2x forEach loop not recommended?

Comment: I added the solution with 2 forEachs but then you are modifying the original object.

Answer (score 1):

As you already know, `Array.prototype.map()` returns a new Array containing the modified version.
In your first map function `myObject.map()`, you aren't saving the second map function modified result as the `childrenList` content.
therefore no changes would be stored in the first map function and the result would have no changes.

```js
const alteredObject = myObject.map((thisChild) => {
  if (thisChild.id === 1) {
    // Here you should save the result of this 
    // Array.prototype.map() Function as the new 'thisChild.childrenList'
    thisChild.childrenList = thisChild.childrenList.map((item) => {
      // ...
    });
  }
  return thisChild;
});
```

```js
const myObject = [{
    id: 1,
    childrenList: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'foo',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'foo',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    childrenList: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'foo',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'foo',
      },
    ],
  },
];

const alteredObject = myObject.map((thisChild) => {
  if (thisChild.id === 1) {
    thisChild.childrenList = thisChild.childrenList.map((item) => {
      if (item.id === 1) {
        return {
          ...item,
          name: 'bar',
        };
      }
      return item;
    });
  }
  return thisChild;
});

console.log(alteredObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a couple of map calls, we'll alter the `name` value if the firstChild id is 1 and the leaf object id is also 1:

```js
const myObject = [ { id: 1, childrenList: [ { id: 1, name: 'foo', }, { id: 2, name: 'foo', }, ], }, { id: 2, childrenList: [ { id: 1, name: 'foo', }, { id: 2, name: 'foo', }, ], }, ]; 

const alteredObject = myObject.map((thisChild) => {
  return { ...thisChild, childrenList: thisChild.childrenList.map(({id, name}) => { 
      return { id, name: (thisChild.id === 1 && id === 1) ? 'bar': name };
  })}
});
  
  
console.log(alteredObject)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code :

```js
const myObject = [
    {
    id: 1,
    childrenList: [
        { id: 1, name: 'foo', },
        { id: 2, name: 'foo', },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    childrenList: [
        { id: 1, name: 'foo', },
        { id: 2, name: 'foo', },
    ],
  },
];

let result = myObject.map(
    el => el.id === 1 ? 
    {...el, childrenList: el.childrenList.map(child => child.id === 1 ? {...child, name: 'bar'} : child)} 
    : el
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The array `map` method creates a new array ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)), so the parent object `alteredObject` still has the `childrenList` key pointing to the original array.
To solve this, you can add assignment of the new array to the key:

```
thisChild.childrenList = thisChild.childrenList.map(...)
```

This way, the key will point to the newly created array

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `return`; you have to return the modified `thisChild` as `{...thisChild, childrenList:modifiedChildrenList}`

```js
const myObject = [{ id: 1, childrenList: [{ id: 1, name: 'foo', }, { id: 2, name: 'foo', }, ], }, { id: 2, childrenList: [{ id: 1, name: 'foo', }, { id: 2, name: 'foo', }, ], }, ];

const alteredObject = myObject.map((thisChild) => {
  if (thisChild.id === 1) {
    return {...thisChild,childrenList:thisChild.childrenList.map((item) => {
        if (item.id === 1) {
          return {
            ...item,
            name: 'bar',
          };
        }
        return item;
      })
    }
  }
  return thisChild;
});

console.log(alteredObject);
```

Comment: There is something missing:

Result: 
[
  [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "bar"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "foo"
    }
  ],
  {
    "id": 2,
    "childrenList": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "foo"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "foo"
      }
    ]
  }

is not equal to the one expected. Missing first parent object with id 1 in the  array

Comment: You're quite right; it's fixed now.